# When I shrink the window and click on the hamburger icon, nothing shows up

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I shrink the window to mobile size and click the hamburger/drop down icon, the rest of the menu is supposed to show. But it's not responding to my javascript dropdownmenu function(). Nothing is showing up. Here is my complete code. Please help me.

Basically in my HTML code, I created a navigation bar. On regular windows page all menu item shows up except the dropdown icon. When I shrink the size, only first menu item shows up ("Home") and a hamburger drop down icon shows up. I use a javascript function DropDownMenu which runs when the browser detects a click on the hambuger icon, which is supposed to drop down the rest of the menu items, but does not.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navmenu" id="dropdownClick">
            <li><a href=“#home”>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="dropdownMenu()"></a>&#9776;</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<script>
    function dropdownMenu(){
        var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
        if(x.className === "navmenu"){
             x.className += " responsive"; 
        }else{
            x.className = "navmenu";
        }
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
/*****************DEFAULTS******************/
html{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

nav, header, footer{
    display:block;
}

body{
    line-height: 1;
    margin:0;
}

/*****************NAV BAR******************/


ul.navmenu{
    background-color:aliceblue;
    font-size:14px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.navmenu li{ 
    display: block;
    padding:12px;
    float:left;
}

ul.navmenu li:hover{
    background-color:aqua;
}

ul.navmenu li a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    min-height:16px;
    color:gray
}

ul.navmenu li.topnav-right{
    float:right;
}

ul.navmenu li.dropdownIcon{
    display:none;
}

/*****************MOBILE******************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px){
    ul.navmenu li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display:none;
    }
    ul.navmenu li.dropdownIcon{
        display:block;
        float: right;
    }

    ul.navmenu.responsive li.dropdownIcon{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    ul.navmenu.responsive{
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.navmenu.responsive li{
        display:inline;
        float:none;
    }
    ul.navmenu.responsive li a{
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
<li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu()"></a>&#9776;</li>
```

on correct version:

```
<li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu()">&#9776;</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. That doesn't solve my problem though unfortunately

Edit: actually it does! Thanks :)